# Motion RTSP streaming from Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, streaming, motion

I'm trying to get streaming from raspberry pi camera to my motion server.

1. Raspberry pi (10.10.84.2) has VLC for RTSP and is run like this:

   raspivid -o - -t 0 |cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264

And when I try to connect to it from other VLC on my PC it works fine.
After it I setup motion.conf to fetch the same URL: rtsp://10.10.84.2:8554/

```
netcam_url rtsp://10.10.84.2:8554/
```

And in log file of motion:

```
[2] [ERR] [NET] [Dec 29 08:07:10] netcam_rtsp_open_context: unable to open input(rtsp://10.10.84.2:8554/): Protocol not supported
```

I have built motion from MrDave source with ffmpeg support .. 
Does anoyne know why this happens ?

Thank you